# How to combine two types when merging in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

TypeScript does not work combining two objects that have the same properties.

if the development mode I want to combine two configs.

```
 if (mode === 'development') {
    return merge(productionConfig, Configuration);
  }
```

The interfaces have the following

```
export type IConfiguration = {
  devServer: {
    port: number;
    historyApiFallback: boolean;
  };
};

export interface IproductionConfig {
  entry: {
    main: string[];
  };
  devServer?: {
    port: number;
    historyApiFallback: boolean;
  };
}
```

when merging in the merge function, I get an error

Argument of type 'IConfiguration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IproductionConfig'.
Property 'entry' is missing in type 'IConfiguration' but required in type 'IproductionConfig'.

Although I have specified all the necessary properties, how can I fix it?

webpack config file

```
import { IproductionConfig } from './types';
import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
import { Configuration } from './dev.config';

const MAIN = 'main';

const Config = (mode: string): IproductionConfig => {
  const isProduction = mode === 'production';
  const isDevelopment = mode === 'development';

  return {
    entry: {
      [MAIN]: ['./src/index.js'],
    },
  };
};

module.exports = (env, { mode }): IproductionConfig => {
  const product = Config(mode);

  if (mode === 'development') {
    return merge(product, Configuration);
  }

  return product;
};
```

dev config file

```
import { IConfiguration } from './types';

export const Configuration: IConfiguration = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did not supply all of the necessary parameters, you are not supplying `entry` which is causing the error.

Comment: I know, but it seems to me that it is not correct to specify this property in the devserver file, since it should not be in it

Comment: to get duplicated properties, it seems to me that this is not correct?

Comment: In that case, you should make that property optional then.

Comment: It would not be duplicated properties, it would instead just overwrite the properties.

Comment: it will only work if you make all the properties optional. It seems to me that this is also not quite correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found a nifty way of typing this in TS by chance.

This tweet from [@tannerlinsley](https://twitter.com/tannerlinsley/status/1623002318349414400) :

And the [reply](https://twitter.com/GabrielVergnaud/status/1623005354471616516?s=20&t=nCPH65QLCTj2hrOG5ZoNgQ) to it:

So you need this type that intersects based on whether the key is required or not: `[TypeScript Playground][1]`

Based on that I have created a [TS Playground solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=156#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxAUygc2QXzgMyhEOAIgHdkAjMAQwGMBrAWhXWSLgCh3kAPSWOGAE8wyOAEkAwhAB2OYGgCuUKjGAy4AXkTs4cACbIAbgGVUh1AC5tu3XxhXpCkOVQBuHTYAWwAM4xoggCCYMAAYlQANhHktHRW5BAQEchU0u66mO6ZnDx2cMDSMKg4tKJiYPh6CjSqMlKy8tZwyIVQglYIHrogVAVWflAFaADaALrpcNm6BiZmqAD8HV1wdg5OLlATut5%20AcFhkdGx8YnJqRPZmJw0Mn5w9XJoVuWV1bXSD41anTbNre1NX5EHoFIhWYYAcgAdAB6HxQGgwgoGbhQgBWPghowANMsrtl2DdpHdPoplO9nqSlCo1NJNE0ZqYoOYoEtfqs4ABmAAMvNxvx2-ja%203CURi9CsMCgCmQ-Mm7Cu7CEInuBDACiKAB4ACoAPnpCDgwwA0vk6XRkIIIDg4NrRlZtSbRpM4AAfODSIyoTjK0SBKLGy0%20HX6rTa5rcIrSPQ%20OCpQRweZwC1Wm3hhxezY%204SiACyqAwAFVpLSddi4IHBLGeFGY8nLdbbfSU429fSpOANchNR4fr8jaaChWg-bbSaRxc4AAyXvLXQms1wf0RSvBvWjRZNmstOvxuf9pOm7fR2MttP7-s2JOO42jC%20XuAZln33RPtweK667Mq-MsPTF2lK3pX8ixLGRNReCAqhqWlSTdcQqXJWl9U4QlbngZgMD0OCtEw7sQOQf8wOkStdQAClJctEJpGQAEp3E4IA)

The gist is this:

```
type Compute<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } | never

type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;

type MergeUnion<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Compute<
  {
      [K in Keys]: T[Keys];
  } &
  {
      [K in AllKeys<T>]?: T extends any
          ? K extends keyof T
              ? T[K]
              : never
          : never;
  }
>

type MergedUnionKey = MergeUnion<IproductionConfig | IConfiguration> 


const mergedConfig = merge<MergedUnionKey>(Config, Configuration);
```

### *****Wrong Answer Below*** doesn't work**

You can create a third type `MergedConfig` and use that instead of `IproductionConfig`

e.g.

```
const Config: IproductionConfig = {
    entry: {
      "main": ['./src/index.js'],
    }
};

const Configuration: IConfiguration = {
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
}

type MergedConfig = IConfiguration & IproductionConfig

const mergedConfig: MergedConfig = {
    ...Config,
    ...Configuration
}
```

This should work since it's a union of both of their properties.

Comment: not work const mergedConfig: MergedConfig
'mergedConfig' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Type '{ devServer: { port: number; historyApiFallback: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MergedConfig'.
  Property 'entry' is missing in type '{ devServer: { port: number; historyApiFallback: boolean; }; }' but required in type 'IproductionConfig

Comment: I think it will only help here not to use the merge function and write everything together in one config

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out and see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the answer later. It seems to me easier to transfer the server config and make them together and write one type